FSCalendarView Calendar swiping months issue in swiftui
I have added FSCalendarView package in project and
i have created like this in calendar initially fillDefaultColorFor is showing properly but when i change month then it is not updating and as well not being called also why? how to fix this issue?
struct CalendarData {
    var date: Date
    var status: Int
}

struct FSCalendarView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var calendarData: [CalendarData]
    var onMonthChange: (Date) -> Void
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, FSCalendarDelegate, FSCalendarDataSource, FSCalendarDelegateAppearance {
        var parent: FSCalendarView
        
        init(parent: FSCalendarView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, shouldSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) -> Bool {
            return false
        }
        
        func calendarCurrentPageDidChange(_ calendar: FSCalendar) {
            // Trigger the onMonthChange closure when the user swipes to a new month
            let newStartDate = calendar.currentPage

            print("Current Month Changed to: \(newStartDate)") 
            parent.onMonthChange(newStartDate)
            calendar.reloadData()
        }
        
        func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, fillDefaultColorFor date: Date) -> UIColor? {
            if let calendarEntry = parent.calendarData.first(where: { Calendar.current.isDate($0.date, inSameDayAs: date) }) {
                switch calendarEntry.status {
                case 1:
                    return UIColor(Color.brandColor) // Present
                case 2:
                    return UIColor.red   // Absent
                case 3:
                    return UIColor(Color.yellow) // Leave
                case 6:
                    return UIColor.blue   // Holiday
                case 7:
                    return UIColor.gray // weekoff
                default:
                    return nil
                }
            }
            return nil
        }
        
        // Set text color for dates based on status
        func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, titleDefaultColorFor date: Date) -> UIColor? {
            if let calendarEntry = parent.calendarData.first(where: { Calendar.current.isDate($0.date, inSameDayAs: date) }) {
                return UIColor.white
            }
            return UIColor.black
        }
    }
    
    // Create FSCalendar view controller
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let viewController = UIViewController()
        
        // Create and configure the FSCalendar instance
        let calendar = FSCalendar()
        calendar.delegate = context.coordinator
        calendar.dataSource = context.coordinator
        
        calendar.appearance.headerDateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
        calendar.appearance.headerTitleColor = .white
        calendar.appearance.weekdayTextColor = .darkGray
        calendar.appearance.titleDefaultColor = .label
        //        calendar.appearance.selectionColor = .systemRed
        calendar.appearance.titleTodayColor = .black
        calendar.appearance.todayColor = .clear
        
        calendar.placeholderType = .none
        calendar.calendarHeaderView.backgroundColor = UIColor(Color.appGreen)
        calendar.calendarWeekdayView.backgroundColor = (UIColor.lightGray).withAlphaComponent(0.5)//UIColor.lightGray
        
        viewController.view.addSubview(calendar)
        calendar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            calendar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.topAnchor),
            calendar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.bottomAnchor),
            calendar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.leadingAnchor),
            calendar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
        
        return viewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        if let calendar = uiViewController.view.subviews.first(where: { $0 is FSCalendar }) as? FSCalendar {
            calendar.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
}

o/p

Current Month Changed to: 2024-08-31 18:30:00 +0000

